# Can you ignore case while using replace?

Tags: twig

Pretty self explanatory. For example, I would want both `test` and `Test` to be replaced:

```
{{ var|replace({"test": 'replaced'}, ignore) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` filter is [defined as a wrapper for `strtr`](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php#L132), so there's no built-in way to do that.

[Extending twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) is easy! Simply create a new filter called `ireplace` (or something else you find appropriate) that uses str_ireplace in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think this function is used to replace keywords, not to do a search and replace